# SQL WHERE IN taking a long time to process SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I would like to refactor the following query as it is taking a while to process:

```
SELECT `user_product`.* FROM `user_products` AS `user_product`
INNER JOIN `items` ON (`user_product`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `user_tags` ON (`items`.`id` = `user_tags`.`item_id`)
INNER JOIN `tags` ON (`user_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id`)
WHERE `tags`.`title` IN ('tag3', 'tag')
GROUP BY `items`.`id`
ORDER BY `items`.`created_at` DESC
```

When I `EXPLAIN` I get the following results:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | user_tags    | ALL    | NULL          | user_id | 12      | NULL                 | 27802 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | user_product | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | 22676 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | items        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | user_product.item_id | 1     | Using where                     |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | tags         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,title | PRIMARY | 4       | user_tags.tag_id     | 1     | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

The query takes 17 seconds with two tags in the `WHERE IN` and 0.009 with one. What would be the best way to optimise the query?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the WHERE IN out into separate WHERE, OR clauses?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns used in the joins?

Comment: Maybe an EXPLAIN without the WHERE IN part could be useful for comparison

Comment: @ypercube thanks for the nudge - it's much faster with an index on ``user_tags`.`item_id``

Comment: The common indexing on a junction (many-to-many) table is to have 2 compound indexes: both `(item_id, tag_id)` and `(tag_id, item_id)`. But your table name suggets that your design is more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an index on user_tags.item_id and also user_products.item_id

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to do. I was also missing one from ``user_tags`.`tag_id``

Answer (score 0):

MySQL should handle a set of constants just fine in an `in` statement.  Have you timed the query for each tag independently?  One of the tags might have a lot of data.

It would probably also help if you had an index on tags.title.

Comment: Just tried querying for each tag and they both come back under 0.2. There is a unique index on `tags.title`.

Comment: I'll be curious what others come up with.  Clearly this is somehow triggering an inferior execution plan.  Are statistics up to date on the table?